# Python: Create Generators at Runtime

Tags: python, language-features, corecursion

I know in python classes and functions can be created at runtime using type and lambda respectively, but can generators be created at runtime?

Example: 
keyword, condition, action, yield

`lambda x,a: a<x,a++,a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are asking for?  If by defined at runtime, you mean, without having to explicitly create a function that uses the yield keyword, then yes, you can use [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

```
>>> t = [1, 2, 3]
>>> (i*2 for i in t)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f1f72dbfdc0>
```